# Can I use the ubuntu default postgres with heroku?

Tags: postgresql, web-applications, ubuntu, heroku, debian

I'm writing a web app to run on heroku using postgresql. On their servers, an environment variable is provided like:

```
export DATABASE_URL=postgresql://localhost:5432/iqtest
```

They advise that when running your app locally, you should disable the usual postgres setup used in debian/ubuntu, and run the server locally 'to avoid permissions issues'.

you can create a database like:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/initdb pg
```

and then run the server like:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/postgres -D pg
```

This actually works fine, but I wonder if it's possible to do it with the system setup instead.

I can't find a simple explanation of how the debian/ubuntu standard setup is supposed to work or how you're supposed to use it, and my experiments have all ended with something demanding my password, and usually warning me that it's then going to write it to disk as plaintext.

Has anyone managed to get the standard setup to work with a heroku-style app without having to do anything appalling?

As a secondary question, is there a graphical (or text ui) browser/editor for postgres tables? Obviously I can use psql and sql commands, but point and click would be much nicer. pgadmin3 won't even connect to the database if I'm running it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be fine to use the system Ubuntu version instead.  I don't really know what they mean regarding permission issues but my guess would be that the pg_hba.conf file is confusing to people and suggesting the default insecure initdb configuration (where no passwords are set) is considered easier than documenting it.

Before doing this you want to review the docs on this file.  Reading the file comments helps but it is no substitute for the docs.  Assuming you are on PostgreSQL 9.1, the docs are at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html.  There were some changes to the files in 9.1, so if you are on an earlier version you should check the docs for your version.